# image display error in html seems with correct path

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, go

I wanna show a image in html file, backend side is golang project, I found the path has already returned by backend and http status is 200, just as below:

[image]

and my image file is below in backend server:

[image]
however there is a display issue as below, and other form elements can be showed normally

[image]
here is my html codes:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>userinfo</title>
</head>

<body>
<img src="{{.Headurl}}"/>
<form action="/userinfo" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>username</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" readonly="readonly" value="{{.Username}}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" readonly="readonly" value="{{.Password}}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>nickname</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nickname" value="{{.Nickname}}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>file</td>
            <td><input type="file" id="file" name="upload"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="update">
</form>
<script>
    $("#file").on("change", function () {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("picture", $("#file")[0].files[0]);
        formData.append("username", $("#username")[0].value)
        formData.append("password", $("#password")[0].value)
        $.ajax({
            url: "/uploadHeadurlHandler",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<a href="/">back to homepage</a>
<a href="/logout">logout</a>
</body>

</html>
```

anyone can help with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is for image but the `Response Headers` have `Content-Type` set to `text/html` instead of `image/jpeg`, which could be possibly causing this issue. Try setting the header correctly in your `Go` server code.

Comment: seems make sense, let me try it first